# What is the area of a single petal/leaf of a rose curve?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area, polar-coordinates

The function given is $r=12\cos(3\theta)$, the graph of this function shows a $3$ petal/leaf rose. Now one way to find the area of a single petal is to do $\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{2π}\int_{0}^{12\cos(3\theta)} r drd\theta$ this gives the value $24\pi$
another way which should give the same value is $2 \int_{0}^{\pi/6}\int_{0}^{12\cos(3\theta)} r drd\theta$
but this equals $12\pi$.
What is wrong here?

Comment: The latter is correct! The former will be correct if you integrate over $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: When $0\le\theta\le 2\pi$, the point crosses the whole "rose" curve *twice*. That is why the first result is exaggerated by the factor of $2$. BTW In general, I would be suspicious about any calculation in polar co-ordinates where $r<0$ can occur: those are easy to get wrong. Thus, even if the first calculation was right,  I would still prefer the second one - for that reason.

Comment: the reason I put it from 0 to 2π is because in the graph if you go one circle around the whole thing you pass through 3 petals

Comment: Try finding areas for all roses $r=R\sin n\theta$ as an exercise.

Comment: @desterman True, and you do it twice. Once when the angle is between $0$ and $\pi$ and once again when the angle is between $\pi$ and $2\pi$.

Comment: Alright I got it you're right since the empty part after π/6 in the first quadrant counts as a petal, it is the same as the one in the third quadrant and so on for the rest right? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following animation (created with PSTricks) might be useful for finding the integration interval.

[image]

For the former, you have to change the interval of the outer integral as follows.
\begin{align}
A&=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^\pi\int_0^{12\cos 3\theta} r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=12\pi
\end{align}